# How to correctly query xml fragment with xPath and XmlNamespaceManager

Tags: xml, sharepoint, xpath

Given the following fragment from SharePoint

```
<listitems xmlns:s="uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882" xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
    <rs:data ItemCount="1">
        <z:row ows_ID="234" ows_MetaInfo="234;#" ows__ModerationStatus="0" ows__Level="1" ows_owshiddenversion="3" ows_UniqueId="234;#{94103987-5DD9-40DF-87B0-A13D76FA6875}" ows_FSObjType="234;#0" ows_Created="2010-06-25 14:28:22" ows_FileRef="234;#sites/dept/Lists/Office List/234_.000" />
    </rs:data>
</listitems>
```

How might I get the value 234 from the ows_ID attribute?

I've tried quite a few ways, and below is the latest attempt

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod6()
    {
        var xml = File.ReadAllText("OfficeQuery-Sharepoint.xml");
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xml);
        XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);

        var officeId = doc.SelectSingleNode("//data/row[@ows_ID='234']", nsmgr).InnerText;

        Assert.IsNotNull(officeId);
        Assert.IsTrue(officeId == "234");
    }
```

which fails miserably.

Comment: SelectSingleNode returns XmlNode, not the attribute value

Comment: @tpdietz Fixed the selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XPath is incorrect, you're not quite using the XmlNamespaceManager correctly, and you're trying to select the node based on the ID rather than the ID.  A very simple way to deal with this is just use the `local-name()` function in your XPath query.

Here's working code:

```cs
XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(@"<listitems xmlns:s=""uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882"" xmlns:dt=""uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882"" xmlns:rs=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset"" xmlns:z=""#RowsetSchema"" xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/"">
  <rs:data ItemCount=""1"">
    <z:row ows_ID=""234"" ows_MetaInfo=""234;#"" ows__ModerationStatus=""0"" ows__Level=""1"" ows_owshiddenversion=""3"" ows_UniqueId=""234;#{94103987-5DD9-40DF-87B0-A13D76FA6875}"" ows_FSObjType=""234;#0"" ows_Created=""2010-06-25 14:28:22"" ows_FileRef=""234;#sites/dept/Lists/Office List/234_.000"" />
  </rs:data>
</listitems>");

XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("rs", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset");
nsmgr.AddNamespace("z", "#RowsetSchema");


var officeId = doc.SelectSingleNode("//rs:data/z:row/@ows_ID", nsmgr);
if (officeId != null)
    Console.WriteLine(officeId.InnerText);
```

If you're not that comfortable with XPath, you might consider LINQ to XML as an alternative:

```cs
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(@"<listitems xmlns:s=""uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882"" xmlns:dt=""uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882"" xmlns:rs=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset"" xmlns:z=""#RowsetSchema"" xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/"">
  <rs:data ItemCount=""1"">
    <z:row ows_ID=""234"" ows_MetaInfo=""234;#"" ows__ModerationStatus=""0"" ows__Level=""1"" ows_owshiddenversion=""3"" ows_UniqueId=""234;#{94103987-5DD9-40DF-87B0-A13D76FA6875}"" ows_FSObjType=""234;#0"" ows_Created=""2010-06-25 14:28:22"" ows_FileRef=""234;#sites/dept/Lists/Office List/234_.000"" />
  </rs:data>
</listitems>");

XNamespace z = "#RowsetSchema";
var row = doc.Root.Descendants(z + "row").FirstOrDefault();

if (row != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine((string)row.Attribute("ows_ID"));
}


Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Dan Field, you first answer is a working solution, but I would like to see the usage with the NamespaceManager (xPath) if possible.

Comment: Added it to the answer.  I always forget the syntax of that because I rarely use `XmlDocument` anymore.

Comment: and just note, you should check for null on `officeId` - if you try to get the `.InnerText` of null you'll get a NullRef exception.